# How do I set rgb mode in pdf generated by tex editor?

Tags: pdf, editors

Somehow I want to set rgb mode in pdf which is compiled by any TeX editor. I don't know other ways to explain it, just, I want my pdf to be in rgb mode after compiling. I heard that it's possible after putting down something to the main code. What should I do?

Also, I would like to know if there're any tex editors with integrated option in menu where I could configure some settings of generating pdf?

Thank you a lot, I tried my best to explain it....

Comment: Do you mean `\usepackage[rgb]{xcolor}` ???

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I'm told this works. So thank you.

Comment: Well, Heiko Oberdiek answered more extensively

Comment: @ChristianHupfer you both were perfect, haha, thanks)))

Answer (score 2):

## Package `xcolor`

Package `xcolor` supports the specification of target color models:

```
\usepackage[rgb]{xcolor}
```

This will use RGB colors for all colors, managed by the `xcolor` package (`\color` und `\textcolor`).

However, included images, bitmap and PDF images, cannot be converted, because
they are usually passed by reference or included with unchanged data.

## Conversion with ghostscript

Ghostscript can be used to post-process a PDF file to convert all colors including images, e.g.:

```shell
gswin64.exe -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sProcessColorModel=DeviceRGB -sColorConversionStrategy=RGB -sOutputFile=test-rgb.pdf test.pdf
```